# How to do AWS X-Ray logging in a .NET Core application?

Tags: asp.net-core, aws-xray

For .NET applications, it is [clearly documented](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-guide.pdf) how to do logging with Xray. The [mentioned library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSXRayRecorder/) is based on the .NET Framework and does not support .NET Core which became clear to me after installation (warning messages). There is [an alternative](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AWSSDK.XRay) that does not have a .NET Framework dependency. However, the xray documentation does not mention this library so hopefully someone can explain how to do logging with xray within a .NET Core application.

Answer (score 2):

For a .NET core application add this line as soon as your app starts but after you configure log4net. If you're not using log4net then you can choose from a couple other logging options.

`AWSXRayRecorder.RegisterLogger(Amazon.LoggingOptions.Log4Net);`

You'll need to reference this assembly though. https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-dotnet